# Hover one element, and change another (without using Javascript)

Tags: css, hover

I have a nested CSS menu that I can't get the submenus to come up.

I took the code from [A list apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/style2.css).  The example on that site works perfectly fine, but since I have 2 CSS navigational menus on my page, I have to put my HTML elements in different CSS classes.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    ul#lvl1 {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        width:150px; /* Width of Menu Items */
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    li.lvl1 {position:relative}
    ul.lvl2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 149px; /* Set 1px less than menu width */
        top: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    /* Styles for Menu Items */
    li.lvl1 > a {
      display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #777;
        background: #fff; /* IE6 Bug */
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    /* Fix IE. Hide from IE Mac \*/
    *  html.lvl1 > ul > li {float:left;height:1%}
    *  html.lvl1 > ul > li > a {height:1%}
    /* End */
    li.lvl2 > a:hover { color: #E2144A; background: #f9f9f9; } /* Hover Styles */
    li.lvl2 > a { padding: 2px 5px; } /* Sub Menu Styles */
    a.lvl1:hover ul.lvl2 {display: block} /* The magic */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="lvl1">
    <li class="lvl1">
      <a class="lvl1" href="#">item1</a>
      <ul class="lvl2">
        <li class="lvl2">
          <a class="lvl2" href="#">subitem1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lvl1">
      <a class="lvl1" href="#">item2</a>
      <ul class="lvl2">
        <li class="lvl2">
          <a class="lvl2" href="#">subitem2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I hover over the "a" on level 1, the "ul" on level 2 won't come up.  Can someone please shed some light?  I may be missing something obvious.  Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must change your CSS selector to target the lvl2 `<ul>`, since it is not nested anymore (it's a sibling, so use +).

```
a.lvl1:hover + ul.lvl2 {display: block} /* The magic */
```

You should read this
[list of css selectors](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

Or you could move the hover on the lvl1 `<li>`, instead of the anchor

```
li.lvl1:hover ul.lvl2 {display: block} /* The magic */
```

Comment: Browse support for selectors like that varies. If you need to support ie6 then don't do this.

Comment: pity the one who still needs to support ie6!