# How do I change image A when hovering over image B without JavaScript only CSS

Tags: css

I would like to know how to update image A when I hover over image B using only CSS, is it possible? if not how will I do that using only pure JavaScript (no library). But css is really what I want to use....

Comment: The only way I can think to do this, is that if the images are close, you could make a background image that includes variations and move the background position accordingly. Otherwise you will need to us JS, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This depends entirely on your html mark-up, and three relationship between the elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bxXJU/ but I don't know how to make id="hv" change if I hover over id="bg"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hover one element, and change another (without using Javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832603/hover-one-element-and-change-another-without-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends entirely on your mark-up, as I pointed out in the comments. In the absence of seeing any mark-up to work with, I can only post some general suggestions; however it's important to note that the element you want to affect (`F`) must appear later in the DOM (be a child of the element `F`, or be subsequent sibling, or descendant of a subsequent sibling) than the element `E` with which you want to interact.

That said, the following approaches will work, with the associated mark-up:

#### Sibling-based selection:

Hovering over the first `img` inside of `#a` toggles the `display` of the subsequent `img` elements, using the `E ~ F` (general sibling) combinator:

```
<div id="a">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/nature" />
    <img class="first" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/people" />
    <img class="second" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/sports" />    
</div>​​​​​

#a img.second,
#a img.first:hover ~ img.second {
    display: none;
}

#a img:hover ~ img.first {
    display: none;
}

#a img:hover ~ img.second {
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JsX8x/1/).

Hovering over `#a` changes switches the display of the `.first` and `.second` images inside of `#b`, using the `E + F` (immediate sibling) combinator:

```
<div id="a">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​/200/400/nature" />
</div>
<div id="b">
    <img class="first" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/people" />
    <img class="second" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/sports" />    
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

#a,#b {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.2em;
}

img.second {
    display: none;
}

#a:hover + #b img.first {
    display: none;
}
#a:hover + #b img.second {
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JsX8x/).

#### Descendant-based selection:

Using the `E F` general descendant combinator (I'm not actually entirely sure a space character *is* a combinator, but regardless...it's based on `F` being a descendant of `E`):

```
<div id="a">
    <img class="first" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/people" />
    <img class="second" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/sports" />    
</div>​

#a img.second {
    display: none;
}

#a:hover img.first {
    display: none;
}

#a:hover img.second {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JsX8x/2/).

Using `E > F` the immediate-child/immediate-descendant combinator:

```
<div id="a">
    <img class="first" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/people" />
    <div>
        <img class="second" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/sports" />
    </div>
</div>​    div {
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.2em;
}

#a > img {
    display: inline-block;
}

#a:hover img {
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JsX8x/4/).

---

There's *also* the chance to use pseudo-elements and css-generated content (in compliant/up-to-date browsers):

```
<div id="a"></div>​

#a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/people);
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}

​#a:hover::after {
    content: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/animals);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JsX8x/5/).

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case it's easy, since `#bg` is a child of `#hv`

Just change your hover selector from what you have to this:

`#bg:hover #hv {...}`

See my fork of your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xJSQt/

Comment: Thanks see both of you posted almost the same, lol but yes this will work great

Answer (score 2):

To update the background position on the inner element `#hv` when hovering the outer element `#bg`, you can:

See this [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/bxXJU/1/) Example!

```
#bg:hover #hv {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Let´s suppose you have a div like this:

```
<div class="myImage">
```

So, in CSS you set the normal background image, and then you use the :hover pseudo-element to change it to your desired rollover image. Something like:

```
.myImage{ background-image: url(imageA.jpg);} /*Set the normal image*/
.myImage:hover{ background-image: url(imageB.jpg);} /*Set the rollover image*/
```

Comment: I think he means updating another image when you hover over a different one.

Comment: Riiight, missed that one. Anyway it is simple: the selector changes to .myImage:hover myOtherImage{background-image: url(newimage.jpg);}