# How to use the hover property with other elements that aren't in the parent

Tags: html, css, hover

What I'm trying to do is get image B to appear when image A is hovered over.

Here's the hover properties I'm using `img.a:hover img.b {opacity:1;}`

The problem is.. these elements aren't in the same parent.
Here's a jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/LquGC/

I understand that it's not in the same parent but I don't understand why CSS was designed this way. Does anybody know any workarounds for this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-effect-a-different-element

Comment: So am I out of options? I want my page positioned the way I have but moving around the elements till they're siblings badly breaks my page..

Comment: This is What you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983380/how-do-i-change-image-a-when-hovering-over-image-b-without-javascript-only-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately CSS will only effect siblings or children. It can't navigate to its parent's sibling. So there is no pure CSS fix for this.

Here are two ways that may work for you. You can keep your current HTML and use JS to make the hover work, or change your HTML and use CSS hover states.

**[HTML reorder fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/LquGC/2/)**

HTML:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="group1">
         <img class="a" src="http://imgur.com/Y7Cz2Q3.jpg">
         <img class="b" src="http://imgur.com/MMZwSdO.jpg">             
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
         <img class="c" src="http://imgur.com/HHbpx0w.jpg">
         <img class="d" src="http://imgur.com/Q9LfCwH.jpg">     
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.b, .d {
    opacity:0;
    transition: .3s;
    }
img {display: block;}   
.wrapper > div {display: inline-block;}

.group1:hover .b {
    opacity:1;
}

.group2:hover img.d {
    opacity:1;
}
```

**[JQUERY fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/LquGC/3/)**

JS:

```
$('.a').hover(
    function () {
        $('.b').css('opacity','1');
    }, function () {
        $('.b').css('opacity','0');
});
$('.c').hover(
    function () {
        $('.d').css('opacity','1');
    }, function () {
        $('.d').css('opacity','0');
});
```

CSS:

```
.b,.d {
    opacity: 0;
}
```