# How can i make a div image change into an other image by hovering over an other div image?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, transition

How can i make a div image(picturemain.png) change into an other image(for example "pic1") by hovering over an image("pic1") in another div?
Pure css prefered.

```
<div class="allSetupOne">
    <div class="mainIMG">
        <img id="main1" src="picturemain.png">
    </div>

    <div class="otherAngles">
        <img id="pic1" src="pictures/gtemp1.png">
        <img id="pic2" src="pictures/gtemp2.png">
        <img id="pic3" src="pictures/gtemp3.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't in just CSS and HTML... could do it in JS and/or jQuery, would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

[**See this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983380/how-do-i-change-image-a-when-hovering-over-image-b-without-javascript-only-css)

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">
    <img src="im" />
    <img class="first" src="im1" />
    <img class="second" src="im2" />    
</div>​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
#a img.second,
#a img.first:hover ~ img.second {
    display: none;
}

#a img:hover ~ img.first {
    display: none;
}

#a img:hover ~ img.second {
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement **especially** when all you are doing is linking to another answer. In this instance, I have closed the question as a duplicate.