# html hover different div

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a sample code i've been working on and mouse on the text i would like to highlight the menu element by changing the color. I can change the background color but not the actual text color. Could someone help with the fix?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<style type="text/css">
#nav  li {display: inline;}
#nav li  a {color: yellow; text-decoration: none; padding-right: 10px; }
</style>
</head>


<body>
<ul  id="nav">

<li id="a"><a href="#abt">ABOUT </a></li>
<li id="b" ><a href="#sequence">CONTENT</a></li>

</ul>


<div id="abt" onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('white')"> 

<p>
Editorial

Hard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learnt
</p>
</div>

<div id="sequence" onmouseover="chbg1('red')" onmouseout="chbg1('white')"> 

<p>
Editorial

Hard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learntHard choices at Copenhagen
During the Climate Change Conference in 2009, the Obama-BASIC meeting was a watershed, saving Copenhagen from a complete collapse and also marking the emergence of the BASIC quartet as a major force i... »
A year later, no lessons learnt
</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function chbg(color) {
    document.getElementById('a').style.cssText = 'color : black! important';
}

function chbg1(color) {
    document.getElementById('b').style.backgroundColor = color;
}


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Typo, should be `black !important` instead of `black! important`. That aside, just do `.style.color = color;`

Comment: This can be achieved with CSS only, NO need of javascript i think :)

Comment: yeah i tried style.color it does not work.

Comment: i tried css.. but i felt it was a lot more complex so i switched to js :)

Comment: @user3748039 CSS is not complex than js, You can give classes to div and can try this way with `div.class:hover { color:red; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hover one element, and change another (without using Javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832603/hover-one-element-and-change-another-without-using-javascript)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak and SergeevD The element to be styled is followed (in the markup) by the hovered element. You can't do this with css alone.

Comment: As a side-note: If you are in complete control over the CSS try to avoid `!important` where ever possible. It is miss-used to often as a quick-fix instead of writing proper CSS, ending in a plethora of `!important` statements trying to continuously overwriting each other. There should rarely be a need to use `!important` when not interfacing with 3rd party plug-ins or CMS systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because using js, you're changing the `color` of `<li>`, it won't be inherited to the `<a>` inside it  since you've explicitly specified another color (*yellow*) for it. Try something like

css:

```
li.hovered a{
 color: black !important;
}
```

js:

```
function chbg(color) {
 document.getElementById('a').classList.add('hovered');
}
```

or

```
function chbg(color) {
 document.getElementById('a').className+='hovered';
}
```

Comment: Why send `color` as an argument if it is never used?

Comment: @xxec idk, you should ask OP. maybe he has something else to do with it..? in one of the example he provided (*which i copied*) he was setting it to black.

Comment: Sure, but since it's not used in your answer, you could elect to remove it alltogheter, but more likely OP wants it there as the function is called with a color keyword: `onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('white')"`

Comment: @xec maybe he is sending the current color applied to the `<div>`, and he wants to perform some other logic according to it..? maybe it's not even a color, but some code word..? how do i know unless it's purpose is clearly mentioned in question..? it can be anything, hence i didn't remove it. you're simply making assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that strikes me as odd with your code. First of all, your function takes a `color` argument, but is never used.

Secondly, the element with id `a` is the `<li>` and below it is a `<a>` element with its own color. You could try something like the following to target the element with text color directly:

```js
function chbg(color) {
    document.getElementById('a').firstChild.style.color = color;
}
```

Alternatively, use the `document.querySelector` method instead, to avoid relying on the `<a>` being the first child (say there's whitespace text node there instead):

```js
function chbg(color) {
    // css selector "#a a" means look for <a> as a descendant of <element id="a">
    document.querySelector('#a a').style.color = color;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xx2fA/

I should probably also mention that the name of the function is also misleading at this point ;)

Comment: Thanks that worked.. My code seems odd because i'm still in the learning process